# Microsoft.Cognitive Services translator api key not displaying

Tags: api, azure, key, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

I have created a *translator_api* within my resources of Microsoft Azure.
However when I Select the **"Keys"** option within the **Resource Management** Section, it fails to load anything.
I have regenerated the Keys many times over the past days but still nothing..

I have a screen shot of the point I am stuck on as a visual Aid..

http://prntscr.com/edzpwt

Thank you for any Advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the error KeysPropertiesPart MICROSOFT_AZURE_PROJECTOXFORD means that your Azure subscription is not active.  This could be because a free trial expired, a credit card is no longer valid, an invoice hasn't been paid, etc.

Please feel free to open a support case at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/ if you need help getting the Azure subscription enabled again.